# Send workbook via POST without saving

Tags: excel, vba, post, http-post, xlsx

I want to send a dynamically created workbook via a POST request. In case when I have a file, it is easy to do. Is it possible to avoid the part of saving it into the file? Thanks!

Comment: To be honest I don't understand the close votes here, the question is very clear.

Comment: I dont htink that its possible, what about saving it and deleting it after sending? It wont be very fast.

Comment: Anyway, I'm afraid this isn't possible. But you can save the workbook to a temporary file and delete it afterwards. Check out [`GetTempName`](https://analystcave.com/vba-filesystemobject-fso-in-excel/vba-gettempname/) and [`GetSpecialFolder`](https://analystcave.com/vba-filesystemobject-fso-in-excel/vba-get-special-folder/) to build the path to the temporary file.

Comment: Another idea which is probably faster would be to just send the *values* in the workbook as CSV or JSON and build this payload yourself by reading the cells. If you are just interested in the cell values and not formatting, etc., this could be a solution which is also much simpler to read on the server side than an XLSX file.

Comment: @snenson, I want to avoid using a temporary file.

Comment: @CherryDT, I like the idea with JSON.

Comment: @user3725657 Are you in control of the server API? Can you change the behaviour of the server part?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - it is Sharepoint so that I can use only endpoints.

Comment: Well since the Sharepoint server will probably not accept JSON you will need to save the file.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the actual question: This is not possible.

Because you can only send via POST what exists. If you want to send a file, that file needs to exist. If you don't save that file it doesn't exist yet.
So you need at least save it in the temp folder and delete it after sending.

Depending on if you are in control of the server API you can ask for a JSON with the data only, so you can submit the data without the huge overhead of an Excel file. If you are not in control over the server API and Excel files is the only that the API accepts, then your only option is to save the file temporarily.

Comment: _you can only send via POST what exists_ - I understand that, but when we want to POST a simple TXT or CSV file, it is enough to generate the context with plain text. I thought there is an option to convert a dynamically created workbook into such a string (I know there would be some strange chars).

Comment: @user3725657 the only dynamical way would be to save that file. Otherwise you cannot know the file content.